# Using PUT to update one field in Restful API

Tags: laravel, rest

This is my updated code:

```
public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, string $id)
{

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $post->update([
        'name' => $request->filled('name') ? $request->name : $post->name,
        'body' => $request->filled('body') ? $request->body : $post->body,
        'email' => $request->filled('email') ? $request->email : $post->email,
        'phone' => $request->filled('phone') ? $request->phone : $post->phone,
    ]);

    $postResource = new PostResource($post);

    return $this->sentSuccessResponse($postResource, 'success', Response::HTTP_OK);

}
```

And here is my validation code

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|size:10'
    ];
}


protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $response = new Response([
        'errors' => $validator->errors(),
    ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    throw (new ValidationException($validator, $response));
}
```

I'm building a Restful API. My intention is that when I use **PATCH** in Postman to update only one field, the other fields will be automatically filled with their existing data. However, I'm still not passing the Required Validation. Does anyone know where my issue might be?

Comment: Not an answer but typically this sort of operation is done via a `PATCH` request

Comment: @Phil yes i know and tried both method :'). Still cant pass throguh Validation

Comment: 'name' => $request->name !='' ? $request->name : $post->name     ,, Try  this

Comment: If you have problem passing the validation, you need to include how you are calling that endpoint. Also throwing an exception in failed validation is kinda unecesary, laravel does that automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sometimes` rules. Basically, it only validates the field if it exists in the request.

You can update your rules like below,

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'sometimes',
        'body' => 'sometimes',
        'email' => 'sometimes|email',
        'phone' => 'sometimes|size:10'
    ];
}
```

And for updating I would suggest using the below method if you are using the `$fillable` property in your `Post` model.

```
public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, string $id)
{

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $post->update($request->all());

    $postResource = new PostResource($post);

    return $this->sentSuccessResponse($postResource, 'success', Response::HTTP_OK);

}
```